# kubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 upgrade wipes out grub

Tags: grub2

Three ubuntu based systems installed on external drive; boot from external drive.  Upgrade Kubuntu system from 11.10 to 12.04 wiped out grub.  Attempt to boot from external drive results in Grub reporting no partition found three times.  Grub reinstall attempts on my part result in failure with 'cannot stat aufs' message.  Request assistance to restore Grub.

Answer (score 2):

Solved - 
For info - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Repaired the above case for the three installed systems on one external hard drive; and another case where after a clean install of Ub 12.04 (on a different external drive) the intitial result on reboot after completing the install resulted in grub reporting "error: no such partition".

Answer (score 0):

I had the **SAME** problem. 4 times Grub was wiped out. I thought about it, checked the forums and no one had an answer. Then I remembered I had trouble installing 11.04 when I selected "Download Updates" during the installation. I read on a forum not to select the updates during the install and do the updates in terminal after the installation completed. So the **5th** time I installed the upgrade from Terminal. Sudo "do-release-upgrade -d". Worked perfectly with no issues. I was prompted where to install grub and the installation confirmed it had found **ALL** of the operating systems I had installed and added them to the list. I ran all the applicantions I have installed with no issues what so ever and 12.04 seems faster. Good luck...